# Is it possible to implement mouse driver with pointer in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, cursor, mouse, driver

I am writing Bluetooth mouse driver app for android. I want to know is that possible to implement mouse cursor in same fashion as on desktop?

What I have done so far is that I have connected my HID mouse to android device via Bluetooth. Mouse is sending reports to device and the Intent service receive it and parse it broadcast x and y coordinates. Now I want to display cursor with same functionality as on desktop.

Is that possible, and if so, how is it done?

Comment: how did you achieve the HID connectivity and how did you decode the HID data reports? HAve you implemented a parser for the Report Descriptor yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's been done, and mouse support is included in android from 3.1 up.

Just wait for an update to your device.

Comment: Is that possible on android 2.* also ? If i am implement it for 2.2 or 2.3 will it work ?

Comment: like a moving cursor on screen .

Comment: It's possible that you could try to backport it, but since that would require a TON of work, you'd be better off contributing to an ICS custom rom for your device. What device is this targeted at?

Comment: for all devices , my client require generic mouse driver that works for all . :-(